# How to make Trigger enter working in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i'm trying to make character to lose 1 hp when it hits enemys trigger, but it's not working
I'm using OnTriggerEnter2D and debugging triggers name, but there's nothing in logs.

[Enemy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yp8Q3.png)

[Character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYzLA.png)

[Character Controller script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIiov.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a Rigidbody2D component to your Enemy and set it to IsKinematic.  Also, it doesn't look like your Character has a collider attached to it so add a BoxCollider2D to the Character, too (unless it has one, I can't see all of its components).

Objects that have trigger colliders attached also need a rigidbody component even if they aren't physics objects.  Making the rigidbody kinematic will ignore the physics system but allow the collision to be detected.

Comment: Hey, i've tried this, but's still not working, (character has box collider) 
Trigger worked in my another project just fine, but not working in this, i think maybe there's some problem with layers or Z coordinate

Comment: Tick the box that says "Simulated" on the Rigidbody for your Character object.

Comment: Whoops, i found mistake, there was isTrigger on character, my bad, sorry, and thanks for your help